# Storing paypal request id?

Tags: security, paypal

im processing payments with paypal api v2, and in my header i put `paypal-request-id` this is a random generated uuidv4 because this is what it says in the documentation that it is a user generated random number. Now I'm wondering if i should store this request id somewhere if something goes wrong with this payment? Or is there something else i should store about paypal payments so when something goes wrong I can check what went wrong or is all this also viewable from the developer dashboard. The thing i want to avoid is that when something goes wrong that i don't have the data (like id's) to go and check what went wrong. I look forward to everyone's solution and view on this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal-Request-Id is particularly useful for capture API operations, so you can [retry them idempotently](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/idempotency/) in the event of a 500 error. It is not useful for any other purpose.

Your own system's order ID, if unique, should populate the purchase_unit's invoice_id field when creating the order. It should be unique, never before used for a completed order, as duplicate invoice_id order completion attempts are blocked by default (to prevent duplicate payments for the same thing).

Comment: I am putting a `custom_id` in the purchase_units to check if the order is paid. thanks for the response!